# Getting thubnails for previous posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

Been trying to find the right plugin or code to do the following:

When a user clicks on any of my listed catagories on the right-side column, a new page opens up with a list of the posts related to that category.  I would like to get thumbnails to also appear next to the post titles.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks.... who ever can help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail). You can use that in your loop next to the post title.